# How to plot two different graphs on a single figure in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get two different plots as one plot. I will not write down my entire code (is so long), but based on the two small codes below, i get two different time series and I want to put these together in one figure.

My code for the first plot:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15,4))

i = plt.plot(july/july.mean(),label='G')
```

my code for my second plot:

```py
spi3 = pd.read_csv('SPI3.csv',header=0,parse_dates=True)

spi3.plot(y='spi',figsize=(16,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick dirty fix would be to plot dictionaries at first, only then plot with `plt.plot`. Also, if you want to plot in the same figure, define `figsize` only in the first figure you are plotting. (Therefore `plt.figure` is ommitted completely.)

```py
spi3.plot(y='spi',figsize=(16,4))
plt.plot(july/july.mean(),label='G')
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but it only plot one graph (spi3) and not  July/July.mean().. any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure these two lines are the only ones that plot anything?

Comment: yes, and I'm just trying to put them togheter in one plot